# Simplify MySQL Query to Remove Multiple Selects in Where Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query to count the number of work permits and wonder if it can be simplified to remove the large amount of selects to find the permit status. This is running on a web page so I need to keep the amount of data sen and received to a minimum

```
SELECT SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Requested'), 1, 0)) AS requested,
   SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Approved'), 1, 0)) AS approved,
   SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Issued'), 1, 0)) AS issued,
   SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Signed On'), 1, 0)) AS signed_on,
   SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Suspended'), 1, 0)) AS suspended,
   SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Cleared'), 1, 0)) AS cleared,
   SUM(IF(tbl_permit_status.status_id = (SELECT tbl_status.status_id FROM tbl_status WHERE tbl_status.status = 'Cancelled'), 1, 0)) AS cancelled,
   COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tbl_permit_status
  INNER JOIN tbl_permit_number
ON tbl_permit_status.permit_id = tbl_permit_number.permit_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_permit_client
ON tbl_permit_status.permit_id = tbl_permit_client.permit_id
```

Comment: Are you sure this gives you the correct counts? You are only joining on `permit_id`. From their names I gather that the three tables are detail tables on permits. So I imagine for one `permit_id` you may have two `tbl_permit_status` records, three `tbl_permit_number` records and four `tbl_permit_client` records. You'd count 2 x 3 x 4 = 24 records, 12 for one status, 12 for the other. Is this really intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join the status table:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(s.status = 'Requested') AS requested,
  SUM(s.status = 'Approved') AS approved,
  SUM(s.status = 'Issued') AS issued,
  SUM(s.status = 'Signed On') AS signed_on,
  SUM(s.status = 'Suspended') AS suspended,
  SUM(s.status = 'Cleared') AS cleared,
  SUM(s.status = 'Cancelled') AS cancelled,
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tbl_permit_status ps
INNER JOIN tbl_permit_number pm ON ps.permit_id = pm.permit_id
INNER JOIN tbl_permit_client pc ON ps.permit_id = pc.permit_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_status s ON ps.status_id = s.status_id
```

As you can see, you can even simplyfy the `SUM` expressions (i.e. no `IF` needed), because true is 1 and false is 0 in MySQL.

(If `tbl_permit_status.status_id` can be null, then left join the status table instead of inner-joining it in order to get a correct total count.)

Comment: Your solution is not correct because if INNER JOIN are relation 1 to N this will return more records and the SUM will be to big. You consider the case when STATUS-ID is NULL (relation 0 to 1) but you forgot to consider relation 1-N

Comment: @schlebe: I didn't actually. I just wrote a query giving the same result as OP's query. Please see that I was writing a comment on the request, right when your were writing yours on my answer :-) If we wanted to count the statuses only, we wouldn't have to join `tbl_permit_number` and `tbl_permit_client` at all. It remains unclear, what result the OP is actually after and how the tables are related (especially: is `permit_id` unique in one of the tables or not?).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this SELECT command can be reduced to

```
SELECT s.*
      ,COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  (
  SELECT SUM(IF(status = 'Requested' ,1,0)) as requested
        ,SUM(IF(status = 'Approved'  ,1,0)) as approved
        ,...

    FROM tbl_permit_status
  ) as s
  INNER JOIN tbl_permit_number as n
    ON n.permit_id = s.permit_id
  INNER JOIN tbl_permit_client as c
    ON c.permit_id = s.permit_id
```

Remark:
I'm not MySql expert but I know Oracle and TrasactSQL. I hope that MySql accepts embedded SQL (I think that it is standard SQL) and that "as" after view/table are accepted (that is accepted on SqlServer but not on Oracle).